# Unable to understand how vue-router query params work

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I am building an app with the following route settings.

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      component: Dashboard,
      beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
          next('/login');
        } else {
          next();
        }
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/home'
    }
  ]
});
```

I also set query parameters based on some select boxes I have by using `$router.push` say as follows.

```
this.$router.replace({
    query: {
        scope: this.$store.getters.filterScope
    }
});
```

### Problems I have

- Reloading the page removes the query params from the URL.
- Updating one query parameter removes the other one I had. Example - updating `scope` using the above method removes the `dateRange` parameter I already had.

I am using Vuex too so is there any way I can manage these query params using the store?

Answer (score 0):

If you store your parameters in vuex and you don't use **vuex-persistedstate**, when you refresh the page state will be removed.

So, my suggestion for you:

your-awesome-site.com/dashboard?first=hello&second=hi

In your Dashboard component, you can do like this

```
mounted () { 
  console.log(this.$route.params)
  // Update vuex state filterScope
}
```

So you will retrieve your parameters from url and save it in vuex.

Also you can solve your second issue using this.$route.params